# Savant3 template engine error, examine fetch() result

Tags: php, error-handling, template-engine, savant3

i try to use Savant3 but i have always the same error message:

```
error, examine fetch() result
```

My wbx.php containing :

```
session_start();
// include Savant class file
require_once 'lib/Savant3.php';
require_once 'lib/gemel.php';

// initialize template engine
$savant = new Savant3();

// assign template variables
$gemel = new Gemel;
$savant->aliasRead = $gemel->getAlias($username, $domain);


// interpolate variables and display template
$savant->display('template/test.tpl');
```

And my tpl is a simple template in html.
If i try in my wbx.php a `var_dump('$savant->aliasRead');` it's work so it's my template who creat this error.

The location is correct, and my tpl is in template/

**But it doesn't work, don't understand why...**

Comment: and your template with the error looks like?

Comment: just one ligne : template error, examine fetch() result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe construct the Savant3 object as:

```
$config = array(
    'template_path' => array('template')
);  
$savant = new Savant3($config);
```

Comment: Amazing ! You made my day :) after post this StackPost i try to set the path directly in **$savant->display($PATH.'template/test.tpl');**, but it doesn't work. Your solution save me :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have that error message, in my case, it meant that `Savant` is trying to `display` a template that does not exist.

You could do a `echo "<pre> fetch : "; print_r($savant->fetch()); echo "</pre>";` to see more information about the error.

But you need to place this code after the code that displays your template.

Hope it will help someone